# Put all images from directory into HTML

Tags: html, image, directory

I am creating a website with an image slider (owl carousel) and I am looking for a good method to put all the images in my HTML quickly.

I hope so, that there is an alternative method to inputting images, because i have about 40 pictures and adding it manually, by hand, will be very tedious...

Could you guys help me by suggesting tell me a generating app or site or anything?

(I'm using Webstorm, but i didn't find any corresponding feature for this in that.)

Comment: So you have a bunch of images in a folder that you want linked? What server-side language are you using?

Comment: Example for a code for an img:
`code`<div class="item">
<img src="src/img/demo/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg">
</div>`code`

Comment: @Streetlamp    
Yea, i have a relative path for the images such as: "src/img/refs/ <here are the images> "

The customer renting just a simple site storage for their html website.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the list of files is static (you didn't mention if they are created dynamically or not) and you are using Windows a simple approach like this will do:

```
for %i in (*.jpg) do echo ^<img src="%i" /^> >> all.html
```

This will create a all.html file which includes references to your jpgs. Simply run the command from a command line window in the directory where your images are stored.

If you need to have the all.html in some other place either move it there or change to `>> C:\files\html\all.html`. 
Another alternative is to add a path in the parenthesis, like `(C:\files\images\*.jpg)` 
Don't forget to delete the all.html if necessary because the command shown above will always append to an existing file so you might end up with double entries.

Comment: What language in this? By `command-line`, I'm assuming this is batch (Windows). Is this also for bash in linux? Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: @Jonathan yes, this is good old MS DOS style batch programming ;-) So it is limited to Windows, yes.

Comment: @Marged
Ah, that's awesome, i was looking for like this, thanks. Can i run this command outside from the folder where the pics are? Because my html files are not in the same folder with the images. So i want the relative paths from the root folder, and the images are on the following path: "root/src/img/refs". This just will be a smoother solution for the "problem".

Comment: @Marged
Yes, that was what i think. Thank you very much, you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @BélaTóth You are welcome. I saw that you already accepted the answer, thanks for that. You can give it a plus one which will give me even more credits which is quite childish but the reason why most of us are giving answers ;-)

Comment: @Marged
I already gave you plus too, but i have a new account here, so it will be visible later (when i reach higher rank).

Comment: @Marged Totally agree about the reputation point... It's all for the REP POINTS. I've been going off with them (3 times >200 rep in the past week!)

Answer (score 10):

You can't just use HTML for this (the only language tag in your question). You're going to need a server-side language, because they can interact with the server (e.g. reading the filesystem).

PHP is great for this: You can iterate through the folder with the images and *dynamically* add images, so that you don't have to do it manually.

Here's an example:

```
<?php
    $files = scandir('path/to/img/directory/');
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if($file !== "." && $file !== "..") {
            echo "<img src='$file' />";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is a solid solution, but when I used it, it included the "." and ".." of the directory so you would need some code to exclude those.

Comment: @Brettins Updated code to reflect your concern.

Comment: @JonathanLam how can I modify this to *only* include, say `.png` files?

Answer (score 0):

I would use php and make an array and an foreach loop like this:

```
$pictures = array('linkToPicture1', 'linkToPicture2', 'andSoOn');

foreach ($pictures as $picturelink) {
    echo "<img src=".$picturelink.">";
}
```

And edit the HTML inside the foreach loop and add all your links in the $pictures array.

Comment: The OP wanted to avoid typing the names of the images, I think. So using your solution he does not gain much.