# Automating HTML img tagging and class assignment

Tags: html, windows

I have a simple HTML site. The main element is a grid of images. They're all classed with their row and column. There are 5 columns, A-E.

```
    <div class="grid">
                <div class="box 1 a"><img src="./assets/Account-Attempt-4-1.gif"></div>
...
</div>
```

I would like to specify a batch of images (preferably in Windows Explorer) and have them formatted like the child elements of my grid.
Is there something out there that will do this that I'm just bad at Googling for? I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to create a macro in a code editor, like Sublime Text. The macro would incorporate some method of auto incrementing the numbers at the ends of the file names (probably with the use of a plugin), but this is based off of the assumption that all of the images in the folder follow the same naming convention (e.g. `image-1.jpg`, `image-2.jpg`, `image-3.jpg`).

**I think that a better option for you would be to do something like [this answer that I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33588766/2977882).** With a little bit of tweaking, this method should be able to take all of the images inside of a defined directory and return an html file with formatted lines of code.

*Best of luck to you!*