# Generate HTML for images in a directory

Tags: javascript, html, generator

I want to generate the HTML for some images in a directory. There aren't really any apps that'll do this.
I got some sample code from Microsoft Bing. I'm not exactly sure how to get this to work but it looks like it should work. (Don't know if it was a good idea posting it since it's not mine!) Should I do something simpler? Perhaps use relative file paths? I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33588766/16895106) with both the command line and as a batch file with Windows but I couldn't get it to work.:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        img {
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Images in Directory</h1>
    <div id="container">
        <!-- This is where the images will be appended -->
    </div>
    <script>
        // This is a JavaScript code that can fetch the images from the directory and append them to the container div
        // You need to replace the directory name with your own
        var directory = "images"; // The name of the directory that contains the images
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Create a new XMLHttpRequest object
        xhr.open("GET", directory, true); // Send a GET request to the directory
        xhr.responseType = "document"; // Set the response type to document
        xhr.onload = function() { // When the request is loaded
            if (this.status == 200) { // If the status is OK
                var links = this.response.getElementsByTagName("a"); // Get all the links in the response
                for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { // Loop through the links
                    var link = links[i]; // Get the current link
                    var href = link.href; // Get the href attribute of the link
                    if (href.endsWith(".jpg") || href.endsWith(".png") || href.endsWith(".gif")) { // If the href ends with an image extension
                        var img = document.createElement("img"); // Create a new image element
                        img.src = href; // Set the src attribute of the image to the href
                        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(img); // Append the image to the container div
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send(); // Send the request
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result I got was just the H1 header which says "Images in Directory" without images even though there were images in the "images" folder.

Comment: You can't do this with only javascript. You need a script on the server (with PHP, Go_lang, or whatever) to send a request to, that then reads the files in the directory and sends that back. Your Bing code is one example of making such a request. You need a server-side code that can respond.

Comment: So, it sounds like all you are wanting to do is take images from a folder (directory) and have them displayed on a webpage? If you are, I can help. How many images are there and how is your folder structure set up?

Comment: @Brent Haha. Fair point. Node.js, Express.js, or Next.js as examples.

Comment: @Brent I guess I don't know how it gets done by front-end developers since I'm not one. If I want to generate a page for a bunch of pictures, it would take a long time copying and pasting the filenames. I was looking for a quick way to automate this process using a batch script. JavaScript can do it but I need to learn how with a server-side script as suggested by Rickard. Do you know how to do that?